# Dart - initializing final class members depedent on each other

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I like to use final members in my classes whenever it makes sense, but I ran into a problem trying to do something relatively simple:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

class Foo {
  final PictureRecorder recorder;
  final Canvas canvas;
  final int margin;

  Foo({
    this.margin = 10,
  })  : recorder = PictureRecorder(),
        canvas = Canvas(recorder) { // this line errors out
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting from the compiler is:

`The instance member 'recorder' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`

Is there another way of doing what I want without making the `canvas` field non-final?

I know I can make the class look similar "from the outside" using a non-final private field and a custom getter, but it feels like an unnecessary workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of a factory constructor which calls your real (hidden) constructor like this:

```
class Foo {
  final PictureRecorder recorder;
  final Canvas canvas;
  final int margin;

  factory Foo({
    int margin = 10,
  }) {
    final recorder = PictureRecorder();
    final canvas = Canvas(recorder);

    return Foo._(
      recorder: recorder,
      canvas: canvas,
      margin: margin,
    );
  }

  Foo._({
    required this.recorder,
    required this.canvas,
    required this.margin,
  });
}
```

Since we have yet to create any object when running inside the factory body, we are allowed to do anything as long as we return an object compatible with the type which the factory constructor is part of.

So we can create all necessary values and then forward them to our real constructor and prevent the use of any `late` variables.

Comment: What I like about this approach is that there's no risk I'll forget to initialize the `canvas` without it being caught by the compiler. The `late final` solution is simpler, but theoretically a bit more error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `late` keyword for the `canvas`.

```dart
late final Canvas canvas;
```

And the constructor should be updated like this :

```dart
Foo({
    this.margin = 10,
  }) : recorder = PictureRecorder() {
    canvas = Canvas(recorder);
  }
```

Check this post to get more info: https://dev.to/pktintali/late-variables-in-dart-dart-learning-series-1-2opf

Comment: For the sake of completeness: the assignment also needs to be moved into the body of the constructor instead of being in the initializer list.

Comment: my bad, I assumed you already knew that, I'll update

Comment: I did, I just wanted the answer as clear as possible for anyone else reading it in the future - thanks for updating!

Comment: you are right! thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```dart
class Foo {
  final PictureRecorder recorder;
  late final Canvas canvas;
  final int margin;

  Foo({
    this.margin = 10,
  }) : recorder = PictureRecorder() {
    canvas = Canvas(recorder);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround I have in mind, but I'd rather do without:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

class Foo {
  final PictureRecorder recorder;
  Canvas? _canvas;
  final int margin;

  Canvas get canvas => _canvas!;

  PatternVisualizer({
    this.margin = 10,
  }) : recorder = PictureRecorder() {
    _canvas = Canvas(recorder);
  }
}
```